# IRC and Irssihelp

Tags: configuration, irc, irssi

I've been searching around on Google, but I cannot find my answers to doing a specific thing with IRC and in Irssi, so I've come here to see if I can get any answers.

Okay first… in IRC using Irssi, when I'm connected to a IRC network, how can I display what channels are currently available on that network I'm connected to?

I have tried doing `/channel list`
but this doesn't show me anything what I'm looking for, all it shows is this;

```
Channel         Network    Password   Settings
#irssi          IRCnet
```

when I run `/lsusers` I get this;

```
*** There are 655 users and 1662 invisible on 9 servers
*** 16 operator(s) online
*** 1245 channels formed
*** I have 383 clients and 3 servers
*** 383 1500 Current local users 383, max 1500
*** 2317 6083 Current global users 2317, max 6083
```

how can I list to see those channel names it shows there like it would in other IRC clients like Xchat or mIRC?

also I would like someone to be able to clarify something since the irssi guides on commands from the Arch Wiki aren't quite too clear, particularly on the VHosts section --> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/irssi#Virtual_hostname_.28vhost.29

tell if I'm close or on the right track here about setting up and using vhosts with Irssi, it says I should set my virtual hostname inside of `/etc/hosts` if I want to use VHosts on Irssi, is this correct? I tried doing just that, but when I try to connect to an irc network I would get

```
-!- Irssi: Unable to connect server irc.example.net port 6667 [Invalid argument]
```

and refuses to connect at all. In my current `/etc/hosts` file I have 2 entries as default for my local hostname, plus defaults for IPv6;

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      ASUS

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

so if I wanted to set my vhost I would have to replace `ASUS` that my current default uses to something else to be able to use VHost in Irssi am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to determine which #channels are available on a server

`/list`

#### How to set a vhost

vhosts are server-specific.  You will need to check the documentation for the server on which you're interested in setting a vhost.  vhosts can also be referred to as **cloaks**.  You do not set this up on your machine, but instead request it from the irc server.

Some servers allow setup of a vhost via Nickserv or another service, or require you to request a vhost/cloak from a server operator.

- [Freenode Cloaks](https://freenode.net/faq.shtml#cloaks)

Comment: when I do `/list` it doesn't return anything, it just gives me this;

    `*** Channel Users  Name`
    `*** End of /LIST`

after a bit of playing around with some of the irc commands I found that `/quote list` command seems to show all IRC channels available on the network.

Comment: When I use `/list`, it tells me that it's a bad idea and to try `/list -YES`.

Comment: that still brings about the same result.